# How might I delete selected alias queues in IBM Websphere's Queue Manager?

Tags: ibm-mq

How might I delete selected alias queues in IBM Websphere's Queue Manager?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a local sign-on to the server where MQ lives you can use the `runmqsc` facility to issue delete commands:

```
runmqsc qmgrname
delete qa(qalias.name)
```

You can use WebSphere MQ Explorer to remotely delete the QAliases in a graphical user interface.

You can use PCF commands in a custom application to issue delete against the queue.

For any of these, the ID connected to the queue manager must either be in the mqm group or have been granted rights to delete the queue.  If the PCF commands are used (WMQ Explorer or custom code) the ID used must also have been granted access to put messages to `SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE` or be in the mqm group.  There are other GUI clients and applications available but they all rely on the same methods I've outlined here - direct access to `runmqsc` or ability to put to the command queue.

WebSphere MQ Explorer is available fore free download as [SupportPac MS0T](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMS0T).  (The main SupportPacs landing page is [here](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs).

The manual for PCF commands is [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzac.doc/pc10120_.htm).